# How does the following construct compare to plain locks

Tags: c#, concurrency, locking

I'm working on a project where all DB-logic (reading and writing) are surrounded with the following:

```
using(Util.DbRun ()) {
    // Code here
}
```

And I went to look up this DbRun method and found this:

```
static readonly object dbWait = new object();
static public IDisposable DbRun ()
{
    Monitor.Enter (dbWait);
    return new Disposable (() => Monitor.Exit(dbWait));
}
class Disposable : IDisposable
{
    private Action action;
    private volatile bool disposed = false;
    public Disposable (Action action)
    {
        if (action == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException ("action can't be null");
        this.action = action;
    }

    #region IDisposable implementation
    public void Dispose ()
    {
        bool run = false;
        if (!disposed) {
            lock (this) {
                if (!disposed) {
                    run = true;
                    disposed = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (run)
            action ();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And my question is; how does that compare to a general `lock { /* code here */ }` construct?

Comment: How exactly is this accessed from multiple threads? What is shared? I dont see the point of this.

Comment: This basically seems to be a *really* convoluted way of writing 'lock(dbWait){ }'

Comment: Let me guess - there's a single, open, database connection hiding somewhere else in this codebase, but the system is trying, desperately, to be multi-threaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's extra code to maintain, and a lot of extra objects for GC to handle (although most of them will die in gen-0, so probably not critical), and a lot of extra lock-handles (which could be mitigated by using `Interlocked` instead of a `lock(this)` in the dispose).

It also doesn't *quite* handle the **very unlikely** edge case that caused the introduction of the [`Monitor.Enter(object, ref bool)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289498) usage in the current compiler, [described here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx), although that could probably be added.

My biggest question, though, would be: why? what problem is it solving? what is it doing **better** to justify existence?

If I wanted to do that *for a valid reason*, then personally I would do away with the delegate usage, and write a custom, implementation-specific disposable object. The delegate is unnecessary complication.

Also: static locks are not always what you want. I would make it an *instance* and simply make that instance available to where-ever needed it. However... the same approach can be used with `lock`, much more simply.

Comment: I'm not quite sure as to why it was introduced, however, what I can see is that somewhere in the code it's been passed along to other functions, and as far as I can see it's used in some way to allow other threads temporarily access to the DB. I was considering going over it all changing it for lock-statements, thought I'm not sure if I should bother. An important part to notice is that this DbRun method is run from several projects (that include the project defining it). Dunno how that matters though.